# Python Output to CSV file job

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Hi I want my simple code which is the following snippet to output to a CSV file:

print(n_active + n_suspended, n_active, n_suspended)

This code generates an output as following: 100, 60, 40

I want this to output onto a CSV file in three columns: first being the total, second being the active, and third being the suspended.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use csv.writer method from pythons inbuilt module csv
here is sample from python doucmentation

```
import csv
with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer